# Elasticsearch custom analyzer not working

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I am using elasticsearch as my search engine, I am now trying to create an custom analyzer to make the field value just lowercase. The following is my code:

**Create index and mapping**

```
create index with a custom analyzer named test_lowercase：

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_lowercase": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "^.*$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

create a mapping using the test_lowercase analyzer for the address field：

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/_mapping/Users' -d '{
  "Users": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "test_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**To verify if the test_lowercase analyzer work:**

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=test_lowercase&pretty' -d '
Beijing China
'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "\nbeijing china\n",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 15,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
```

As we can see, the string 'Beijing China' is indexed as a single lowercase-ed whole term 'beijing china', so the test_lowercase analyzer works fine.

**To verify if the field 'address' is using the lowercase analyzer:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?field=address&pretty' -d '
Beijing China
'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "\nbeijing china\n",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 15,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?field=name&pretty' -d '
Beijing China
'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "beijing",
    "start_offset" : 1,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "china",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

As we can see, for the same string 'Beijing China', if we use field=address to analyze, it creates a single item 'beijing china', when using field=name, we got two items 'beijing' and 'china', so it seems the field address is using my custom analyzer 'test_lowercase'.

**Insert a document to the test index to see if the analyzer works for documents**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/Users/12345?pretty' -d '{"name": "Jinshui Tang",  "address": "Beijing China"}'
```

Unfortunately, the document has been successfully inserted but the address field has not been correctly analyzed. I can't search out it by using the wildcard query as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/Users/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "address": "*beijing ch*"
    }
  }
}'
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

**List all terms analyzed for the document:**

So I run the following commands to see all terms of the document, and I found that the 'Beijing China' is not in the term vector at all.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/Users/12345/_termvector?fields=*&pretty'
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "Users",
  "_id" : "12345",
  "_version" : 3,
  "found" : true,
  "took" : 2,
  "term_vectors" : {
    "name" : {
      "field_statistics" : {
        "sum_doc_freq" : 2,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "sum_ttf" : 2
      },
      "terms" : {
        "jinshui" : {
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [ {
            "position" : 0,
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 7
          } ]
        },
        "tang" : {
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [ {
            "position" : 1,
            "start_offset" : 8,
            "end_offset" : 12
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can see that the name is correctly analyzed and it became two terms 'jinshui' and 'tang', but the address is lost.

Can anyone please help? Is there anything missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To lowercase the text you don't need a `pattern`. Use something like this:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "test_lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/_mapping/Users
{
  "Users": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "test_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test/Users/12345
{"name": "Jinshui Tang",  "address": "Beijing China"}
```

And to verify you did the right thing, use this:

```
GET /test/Users/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["name", "address"]
}
```

And you will see **exactly** how Elasticsearch is indexing your data:

```
        "fields": {
           "name": [
              "jinshui",
              "tang"
           ],
           "address": [
              "beijing",
              "china"
           ]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei Stefan. I need lowercase and I need the whole value of the address to be a single item instead of splitting into words. For example, 'Beijing China', I don't want 'beijing' and 'china', instead, i want a single term 'beijing china' so that users can search it with wildcard '\*jing chi\*'.

Comment: I updated my answer and changed the `analyzer` from `standard` to `keyword`. Try that.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, yes. your code works for me, it is exactly what I want.  I will accept your answer. But do you know what is the problem with my pattern analyzer?

Comment: The pattern analyzer splits the text given a certain pattern and, yes, by default it's lowercasing the terms. The pattern should match the token separators. In your case there is no such thing because you want the whole text to match. In this case I think the pattern should have been `"pattern": "^"`. But again, this is not the recommended way of lowercasing and keeping the text intact. Regular expressions probably have worse performance than my suggestion.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again! Yes, keyword should be better than regular expression.